# Code analysis with Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, code-analysis, static-code-analysis

I am trying to utilize code analysis for the first time with Visual Studio 2012. When I enable code analysis on build I get following error

```
    2>c1xxast : fatal error C1250: Unable to load plug-in '  local_path\packages\Microsoft.CppCoreCheck.14.0.24210.1\build\native\\EspXEngine.dll'.
```

Is it due to the two backward slashes at the end? How do I fix this?

I am trying to compile it in debug mode - x64 configuration. My project uses precompiled headers.
Any insights appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Typically, two back slashes are not a problem

Comment: That's a Nuget package, it requires at least V2015 Update 1.

Comment: Try simple PVS-Studio tool for VS2010-2015 https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/2cc8fb8e-eb39-4656-bafb-af341471edbd

Answer (score 0):

The C++ Core Checker (that Microsoft.CppCoreCheck NuGet package) requires at least VS2015 Update 1, as explained in the [initial blog post](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2015/12/03/c-core-guidelines-checkers-available-for-vs-2015-update-1/).  You can still run code analysis without the C++ Core Checker, but it will not be check for as many issues.